# Firebase.post is not working in my programme

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my Code in raspberry PI's python(Thonny Idle).

Kindly Ignore the Url, it is not the real address.
Code

```
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://testing123123-iot.firebaseio.com',authentication=None)

data = {
    'Name':'Hi',
    'Email':'hihi.com',
    'Phone':512232131
        }

result = firebase.post('/testing123123-iot:/Customer', data)
print(result)
```

Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/pi/Documents/PythonCode/TestingFirebase-1.py", line 17, in
>
> ```
> result = firebase.post('/testing-iot:/Customer', data)
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/firebase/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
>
> return f(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/firebase/firebase.py", line 329, in post
>
> connection=connection)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/firebase/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
>
> return f(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/firebase/firebase.py", line 97, in make_post_request
>
> timeout=timeout)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 340, in post
>
> return self.request('POST', url, data=data, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 279, in request
>
> resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 374, in send
>
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 174, in send
>
> timeout=timeout
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 417, in urlopen
>
> conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 232, in _get_conn
>
> return conn or self._new_conn()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 547, in _new_conn
>
> strict=self.strict)
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of the error message? Why are there `<br>` tags in there?

Comment: This may be a dumb question - are you using any kind of IDE?.. I was having this exact problem while using Spyder3 in Windows 10.  I tried my exact same code from cmd and was able to interact with firebase.

Answer (score 0):

use json.dumps :

```
import json

data = {
    'Name':'Hi',
    'Email':'hihi.com',
    'Phone':512232131
    }

sent = json.dumps(data)

result = firebase.post('/testing123123-iot:/Customer', sent)
print(result)
```